# Toast error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

the application crashes when I make a toast but I do not understand why. This is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"START!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while( startTime + 5000 >  System.currentTimeMillis())
                    {
            //      }
            //      while (progressStatus < 1000) {

                        if (k > progressStatus){
                            progressStatus = k;
                        }
                        else {
                            progressStatus = progressStatus;
                        }
                        // Update the progress bar and display the current value in the text view
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            // Sleep for 10 milliseconds. Just to display the progress slowly
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Toast mioToast = Toast.makeText(BluetoothChat.this, 
                            "STOP!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                            mioToast.show();

                }

            }).start();

        }

    });
```

the first toast executes it perfectly but in the second, where there is the word "STOP", the application crashes. How so?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display a `Toast` in a background thread. The UI can only be modified from the UI thread, and that's what crashes your app.

Use this instead:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothChat.this, 
                        "STOP!", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

This will run on the UI thread and thus won't crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace "getApplicationContext()" with "this" or "your_class_name.this"